# Can't boot, kernel panic in recovery

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel

I have dual boot of Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04. Currently, when I try to start Ubuntu a blank screen comes up and Caps Lock starts blinking. My only choice is restarting my laptop and using Windows OS.

Also, if I try to start Ubuntu through the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" menu, it gives me error in the console that says "Kernel panic..."

Is this an OS or hardware issue?

Will it be resolved if I reinstall Ubuntu with latest version?

Answer (score 0):

A "Kernel panic" error indicates there is a serious problem with your Linux kernel.

You can find more info on this here:

http://searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/definition/kernel-panic

This could be hardware or software but reinstalling Ubuntu will *probably* fix the problem.

If it doesn't then you likely have a hardware issue, probably with a section of your hard drive having been corrupted. As Windows is working fine, it is unlikely (though just about possible) to be a problem with anything else, like CPU or RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I have just reinstall ubuntu with latest 17.04 version, both the OS are working fine now. also I was able to recover my old data which was in old version of Ubuntu.